# Disabling CamelCase links in Confluence on a per-page basis

Tags: confluence

**Background:** My employer uses Confluence as our knowledgebase wiki, and they've turned on CamelCase links. Since we use a lot of CamelCase in our method names, this results in a lot of extraneous links; we can disable that behavior by wrapping every one of them in {nl:} but that gets tedious and sometimes we miss one. (And since there are many existing pages and not everyone is using it for code discussions, asking IT to change the global setting is a non-starter.)

**Question:** Is there a way to override the global setting, to mark an individual page in Confluence as *not* using CamelCase links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery posted at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-7999?focusedCommentId=237514&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-237514

nocamel macro can be made out of it. The poster and myself are using it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have found. Here are the Confluence docs on the subject:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/CamelCase%20linking

Shame eh?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. Starting a page with a '{nocamel}' macro sometimes disables it on our Confluence, but apparently does not reliably work all the time. It's not an official macro; it's possible our admin did some custom macro, but I doubt it. Perhaps it's an unsupported feature, but it's worth trying.

There are a couple of relevant Confluence feature requests that you might consider voting up. This one for disabling CamelCase linking in a page:
http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-7999

And this for disabling CamelCase linking on whole spaces:
http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-6526